# Quadpy Integration with multiple function Arguments

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Is there a possibility to include more than 1 argument in a quadpy integration?

```py
def function(x,a):
    return a*x**2

scheme = quadpy.line_segment.gauss_legendre(10)
scheme.integrate(function, [0,1])

# function() missing 1 required positional argument
```

Similar to scipy integration:

```py
a=2

scheme.integrate(function, [0,1], args=(a))
```

Comment: Same question asked in the quadpy issue tracker. https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/issues/219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already do that:

```py
import quadpy


def function(x, a):
    return a * x ** 2


scheme = quadpy.c1.gauss_legendre(10)

a = 10
out = scheme.integrate(lambda x: function(x, a), [0, 1])
print(out)
```

```
3.3333333333333326
```